# SQL Puzzle - UNION ALL without UNION ALL

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

Here is the SQL Puzzle to challenge you:

Write a query that would select top 5 records in three different categories.

Something like this:

```
select top 5 name, age from table1 where category = 22 order by age desc
union all
select top 5 name, age from table1 where category = 27 order by age desc
union all
select top 5 name, age from table1 where category = 53 order by age desc
```

But do it **without** using UNION or UNION ALL

If you are using some vendor-specific SQL extensions please specify the database you are using.

Comment: and other way would be three subtables joined on to a 15 record 'skeleton'

Comment: `TOP 5` is vendor-specific.

Comment: Hmmm... you are right. TOP 5  is vendor specific! Haha! What staying on a single DB for a while could do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic `top-n-per-group`, isn't it?

Using SQL Server syntax. `ROW_NUMBER()` should be in all decent databases in 2015.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    select 
        name
        ,age
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY age desc) AS rn
    from table1
    where category IN (22, 27, 53)
)
SELECT
    name
    ,age
FROM CTE
WHERE rn <= 5
;
```

---

`UNION` is in some sense the same as `OR`.

If your table has a primary key `ID` you can rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT name, age
FROM table1
WHERE
    ID IN (select top 5 ID from table1 where category = 22 order by age desc)
    OR
    ID IN (select top 5 ID from table1 where category = 27 order by age desc)
    OR
    ID IN (select top 5 ID from table1 where category = 53 order by age desc)
```

Normally, `UNION ALL` would be more efficient than this, though.

Comment: CTE here is just to make it easier to write, but `ROW_NUMBER` is the critical part. Does intersystems-cache have something similar?

Comment: OP did say "If you are using some vendor-specific SQL extensions please specify the database you are using"

Comment: No, no ROW_NUMBER in Cache'

Comment: @Anton, but it seems that Cache has [`UNION ALL`](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_union), so why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Yes it does. No practical reason. It's just a puzzle, not a real life problem.

Comment: @Vladimir - your OR solution is the best I've seen so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you truly want top 5 then you'll probably need a tie-breaker. Is `name` unique per `age`?

```
select t.name, t.age from T t
where t.category in (22, 27, 53) and 5 >= (
    select count(*) from T t2
    where t2.category = t.category
        and (t2.age >= t.age or t2.age = t.age and t2.name >= t.name)
)
```

Comment: Good one and it does the trick. Though your code is for order by age ASC. I had to replace <= with => in a last clause to turn it into age DESC.

Answer (score 2):

> If you are using some vendor-specific SQL extensions please specify
>   the database you are using.

In ***SQL Server***, you can use the ranking function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY category` to generate a ranking number for each group of category, and filter on three categories you are looking for. Then you can filter to get only the rows have ranking number less than 5, this will get you top oldest 5 names for each category:

```
SELECT name, age
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      name, age, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY age DESC)AS RN
    FRO< table1 
    WHERE category IN(22,27, 53)
) AS t
WHERE RN <= 5;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6028b/3)

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is vendor - specific or ANSI SQL?

Comment: @Anton -  What RDBMS you are working with?? You didn't specify a RDBMS

Comment: Any database that supports analytic functions should have row_number, which is pretty much any modern, mainstream RDBMS

Comment: @Anton, `ROW_NUMBER` is [ANSI SQL2003](http://users.atw.hu/sqlnut/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-3.html). Too bad InterSystems Cache doesn't support it. Most likely it has something to mimic it.

Answer (score 1):

Ranking can be expensively simulated with a self join. This is pseudo-SQL (i.e. could need a little syntax tweaking) for a solution with a sub-select doing a self-join. Is this what you meant?

```
select name, age from ( 
  select a.name,a.age, count(*) as rank from 
    table1 a join table1 b on a.category=b.category 
  where a.category in (22,27,53) and 
        ((b.age+hash(b.name,b.age) >=a.age+hash(a.name,a.age))
) c
group by c.name, c.age  
where rank <= 5
```